# High memory usage crf_learn.exe

Tags: c++, c, crf++

I used CRF++ to learn a model with around 6,000 sentences. The trained model has been tested and it proved to work perfectly. Then, I increased the number of sentences to 120,000 sentences. The problem is when I trained the model using the following command line

```
crf_learn template traindata model
```

After crf_learn.exe reading the training data, it suddenly stops working and an error message appears which closed the program and prevented it from completing the steps.
the error message says 
    crf_learn.exe has stopped working correctly. Windows will close the program.

I tried to make the training faster by using multi-threading and cuting-off the threshold for the features as follow:

```
crf_learn -f 30 -c 1.5 template traindata model
```

but the problem still appears and I could not create the trained model! Is there any one have an experience with CRF++? or Is there any way to increase the memory for executable file (.exe) that have already built using C++ when running it from Command line?

Comment: Being open source you should be able to debug it. What is it doing when it crashes? What is the failure? What machine are you running on?

Comment: Hi Andy! Actually I have never used C or C++ in programming! I do not have a compiler for C on my PC. I am afraid to make my PC heavy while I do not need to have C/C++ compiler. Can you recommend a light one! That will take not too much space... My PC has a memory with 4GB and it is Windows 7 professional (64-bit).

Comment: Best use the compiler used to build your version of CRF++. I don't know about "light" compilers: I use MS Visual Studio for some things and G++ for others.